# Swift using delegate written in Objective-C

Tags: delegates, swift, ios8

Im using a custom made class with delegate methods written in objective-c in a swift file. Bridging header is setup thus I am able to refer to classes in .m and .h files in .swift files. Here comes a problem, I was trying to include delegate method to the swift file, and it shows me message **Type '*YourClassName*' does not conform to protocol '*YourDelegateWrittenInObjC*'**. When I **Command + Left Click** on the error message, some message with **gray background** comes out on the delegate method.

Wish someone could help me solving this problem. A print screen is provided to help debug:

[image]

Edited (include delegate declaration):

Here you go:

```
@protocol CollapseClickDelegate
@required
-(int)numberOfCellsForCollapseClick;
-(NSString *)titleForCollapseClickAtIndex:(int)index;
-(NSString *)leftTitleForCollapseClickAtIndex:(int)index;
-(NSString *)rightTitleForCollapseClickAtIndex:(int)index;
-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index;

@optional
-(UIColor *)colorForCollapseClickTitleViewAtIndex:(int)index;
-(UIColor *)colorForTitleLabelAtIndex:(int)index;
-(UIColor *)colorForTitleArrowAtIndex:(int)index;
-(void)didClickCollapseClickCellAtIndex:(int)index isNowOpen:(BOOL)open;

@end
```

Comment: It's clearly complainig about types. The types declared in your delegate methods are different from the one required by the objc class. Please post the objc protocol declaration.

Comment: I added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift primitive types (like `Int`) are automatically bridged to NSNumber when interacting with Objective C.

When you write `Int` on the Swift side, you must have an `NSNumber` on the Objective C side.

Since your objc protocol use `int` (a c primitive type) and not `NSNumber` as the type of some parameters/return value, you should bridge it with the correct type, that is `CInt`

Change all your `Int` with `CInt` on the Swift side and all will work

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13)